# How to configure MediaElements.js plugin to load JS files in WordPress footer?

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

I have been tearing my hair out trying to move all the JavaScript files from the header to the footer in a WordPress blog I am working on.

Currently I am trying to configure MediaElements.js plugin. I am trying to load all the plugin's JS files in the footer.

I've discovered that the mejs_add_header() function in the mediaelement-js-wp.php loads the javascript and css.

```
function mejs_add_header(){
$dir = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/';
echo <<<_end_
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$dir}mediaelementplayer.min.css" type="text/css"  />
    <script src="{$dir}mediaelement-and-player.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    _end_;
}
```

The Javascript isn't being loaded using the WordPress enqueue_script() function. Instead of making changes to this file, is there a way of configuring the plugin to load JS file in the footer?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't heard about that plugin before, but try this somewhere in your functions.php:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'mejs_add_header'); 
add_action('wp_footer', 'mejs_add_header');
```

And if that doesn't work then try looking for where and how that function is being called.

~ K